# Конвертировать время в timestamp

Tags: python, время, datetime

Мне нужно конвертировать

```
my_time = '2020-01-01T12:10:00.000Z'
```

в timestamp. С миллисекундами, чтобы получилось 1577880600000. Для того, чтобы импортировать datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
```

в последней версии Python не нужно делать pip istall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для преобразования объекта типа `datetime` (локальное время) в число секунд, прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00` **UTC** - можно воспользоваться методом [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timestamp):

```
In [53]: from datetime import timezone, datetime as DT

In [54]: DT.strptime(my_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").timestamp()
Out[54]: 1577877000.0
```

PS [таблица форматов для форматирования даты и времени](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

---

Если время уже указано в UTC:

```
In [59]: res = (DT
                .strptime(my_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                .replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
                .timestamp())

In [60]: res
Out[60]: 1577880600.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, про f перед Z  есть в документации?

Comment: @КириллВишняков, дополнил ответ)

Comment: ответ неправильный получился

Comment: время, интересующее меня GMT, не локальное

Comment: поставьте нужное локальное время date.timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'

Comment: В моем вопросе есть правильный ответ. Получается разница ровно в один час.

Comment: @КириллВишняков, см. обновленный ответ

Comment: Спасибо, теперь то